# recover matrix operator $A:[0,1]^n\rightarrow[0,1]^m$, $m\ne n$

Tags: matrices

suppose I have vectors $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ where $x_i \in [0,1]^n$ and $y_i \in [0,1]^m$. I know that $Ax_i = y_i$

In this case, is there any way or any paper that I can recover matrix operator $A$?

I have checked out some papers discussing about low rank matrix recovery, but it seems I am dealing with a different question.

Comment: That depends, are $x_i$ linearly independent?

Comment: @Ian suppose they are, can I recover A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the matrix whose columns are $x_1, \dots, x_n$, and let $Y$ denote the matrix whose columns are $y_1,\dots,y_n$.  You can rewrite your statement on the $x_i$ and $y_i$ as
$$
A X = Y
$$
In your case, the matrix $X$ has $n$ columns and $n$ rows.  This equation will allow you to recover $A$ if and only if the columns $x_i$ are linearly independent; in this case we can compute
$$
A = YX^{-1}
$$
More generally, we can cover $A$ as long as the vectors $x_i$ span $\Bbb R^n$, even if there are more than $n$ of them.

Comment: Suppose if we have $k<n$ number of $x_i$'s. Can we recover some part of A or are we hopeless?

Comment: @user1292919 in that case, we can only recover what $A$ does over the column space of $X$.  In particular: if $x$ is a vector in the column-space of $X$, then we can find a vector $u$ such that $Xu = b$.  From there, we have
$$
Ab = AXu = Yu
$$
if $x$ is not in that column space, however, we are indeed "hopeless".